# How to add residuals values in my data frame?

Tags: statistics

I've residuals value in my model result. I would like to transform and add them in my data frame.That's means, to have results with low residuals values. I'm using FE model. So, i've tried to add but my method doesn't work.  Here my R details:

```
fixed = plm(sp ~lag(debt)+lag(I(debt^2))+outgp++bcour+gvex+vlexp+vlimp, data=bdata, index=c("country", "year"), model="within")
```

method for adding my residuals values:

```
bdata$resid = fixed$resid
```

thanks for your hand

Comment: Hi Emilio, the word in English is "residuals", not "residus". Perhaps a web search for "R plm residuals" or something like that will help.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks, i'e amended... but i've tried to find solutions with the PLM buts i found nothing special. Any ideas?